# Error using luasocket in Eclipse (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, lua, luasocket

I'm trying to use Lua 5.1 with luasocket in Eclipse Luna installed at Ubuntu 16.04.

I've already installed Lua 5.1 and LuaSocket 3.0-rc1 and I can run this program from command line (lua main.lua):

```
print(_VERSION)
print("Path: "..package.path..'\nCPATH: '..package.cpath)
socket = require("socket")
print(socket._VERSION)
```

and the result is:

```
$ lua main.lua
Lua 5.1
Path: ./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua
CPATH: ./?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so
LuaSocket 3.0-rc1
```

But when I try to run the same program using eclipse with lua plugin installed, I get this:

```
Lua 5.1
Path: ;./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/media/meslin/16E65872E6585459/Users/meslin/Google Drive/workspace-desktop-ubuntu/Lua Alo Mundo/src/?.lua;/media/meslin/16E65872E6585459/Users/meslin/Google Drive/workspace-desktop-ubuntu/Lua Alo Mundo/src/?/init.lua;/media/meslin/16E65872E6585459/Users/meslin/Google Drive/workspace-desktop-ubuntu/Lua Alo Mundo/src/?.luac;/media/meslin/16E65872E6585459/Users/meslin/Google Drive/workspace-desktop-ubuntu/Lua Alo Mundo/src/?/init.luac;
CPATH: ./?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so
Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so':
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: lua_gettop
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:143)
```

Any ideas? Can you help me, please?

Thanks
Alexandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue was [discussed on the lua maillist](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-09/msg00134.html) some time ago, see if the recommendation there helps you:

> By default, LDT ships with a built-in Lua VM (based on jnLua) so as anyone without even having to install Lua on its machine can start running Lua scripts real quick. I think that the way you've set the PATH and CPATH, the jnLua VM itself is not found anymore.
>
> What you probably want is to configure a "local interpreter" for your local native VM. You can use [1] as a reference. Once you have the interpreter set up, you can launch the script against this interpreter instead of the embedded jnLua one by tweaking your launch configuration.